# Displaying page views for a Recipe website?

Tags: website-design, metrics, page, counter

I just wanted some opinions on displaying the number of views a recipe has (based on GA page views) with the objective to increase click-throughs.

My hypothesis is displaying the page counter in the form of ‘recipes views’ can be valuable to users as it gives them an indication and impression of how popular a recipe is, which might make them more inclined to trust the recipe if there have been a large number of views.

Comment: Do you plan to present the bounce rate as well?

Comment: I think it would be okay to show as a small note, like how Stack Exchange does it. I wouldn't show it directly on any other page, but it could be useful to get a "popular" section (similar to SE's hot network questions list). Definitely shouldn't be the only way to gauge "quality" though, a proper rating system would be really nice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read more about Social Proof. Maybe instead of showing the views you go with Rating, upvotes. I would assume in recipes people are interested if people tried the recipe and succeded. https://www.nngroup.com/articles/social-proof-ux/

Comment: Recipes are highly culturally-dependent. I'd go with "People who like this recipe also like recipe XYZ", that would be even more useful

Answer (score 9):

A page counter only shows how popular the page is, not how popular the recipe is. If people tend to go to pages that are viewed more than others, but the recipe itself isn't liked very much, the page still gets popular. This can kill the whole concept when people don't trust the numbers anymore. So the amount of page visits are useless without a score, rating or review system. Use both.

Comment: Many recipe sites allow you to say "I made this recipe" and show that counter of people who self-reported in that fashion. I find it useful to compare the number of people who claim to have made it, to the reviews/ratings.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That's a good point. It still requires users to actually claim they made the recipe instead of just assume every user that visits the page has made it. So I believe that can be called a score system? I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A views counter could make the users feel like they are being watched - for some people that might be an uncomfortable experience.

They *are* being watched, but you don't have to show that to them.

Comment: I don't really think this is a concern. View counters are everywhere, including sites like SE and YouTube, and I've never seen anyone concerned by them.